# adding an admin flag to a user along with rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, rails-admin

I have added an admin flag to my users model following the devise wiki here (the second option):

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role

but not in rails_admin the admin flag is disabled, isn't it supposed to be a checkbox instead of a grey circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `rails_admin` automatically disables this field for safety reasons. To re-enable it, you can set the `config.attr_accessible_role` field in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`, like this:

```
config.attr_accessible_role { nil }
```